# How does one add a new line in a cell in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I pressed <kbd>return</kbd> to make a new line in a cell of my Google Spreadsheet. That just moved the cursor to the next cell.

How does one add a new line in a cell?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

When you're focused on the cell press enter to get into edit mode:

- Windows/Linux/Chrome OS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd>(<kbd>Alt</kbd>) + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Linux: `Ctr` + `Enter` works

Comment: If you need a line break in a formula, use `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: On Windows `AltGr + Enter` works too

Comment: What is the option for adding the new line from mobile application of google spread sheet?

Comment: I just facepalmed! Why isn't this SHIFT+Enter, like so many other applications?

Comment: Thanks! Oddly, even *after* reading this, by muscle memory I kept typing SHIFT+Enter and wondering why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 57):

## Amendment

New Line in `Cell Formula` **>>** `CHAR(10)`

#### Example Usage

- `=Concatenate("Line 1", CHAR(10), "Line 2", CHAR(10), "Line 3")`
- `=Join(CHAR(10), "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3")`

#### Why CHAR(10)?

A new line is also known as a `Line Feed`. The hexadecimal [`Unicode Control Code`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes) for a Line Feed is `U+000A`. Therefore, the **decimal value** of a Line Feed is 10.

This decimal value can be used in the [CHAR(...)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en) function in Google Sheets to return the desired character.

---

*Note: Dez's answer does not work for cell formulas. I was searching for adding new-lines in cell formulas, and this StackExchange question popped up. Therefore, I added the above for those that need new lines in formulas. The below is a snapshot of Dez's answer for completeness :)*

> **Dez's [Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25361/53308)**
>
> **In Edit Mode**
>
> - Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  **or** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> - Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd>(<kbd>Alt</kbd>) + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Here's another useful way to do it:
`=JOIN(Char(10), A1,A2,A3...)`

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3")` may even be better to treat empty values