# Return text from multiple cells on another sheet with linefeed if dates match

Tags: google-sheets

I have an example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WPbbzmFP137mG6gGs16LSmdTOxxniJQSR0uzkcjvPw0/edit?usp=sharing) of my spreadsheet.

Basically my main page has a drop-down (via data validation) where you can toggle through any month and it responds by showing data for that month.

What I want to do is be able to type a note for a specific day and have it show up in Sheet1!B2:B where the date in Sheet2!A2:A matches Sheet1!A2:A. So Sheet2 will have any number of notes across any month of the year. If there is a duplicate date in Sheet2!A:A then it could just grab the first or throw error (this will be an edge case). I would even be fine populating Sheet2!A2:A with all 365 days if it would make things easier.

What would be best is if I could just type my change in Sheet1!B2:B and it would grab the date from Sheet1!A2:A and make the entry in Sheet2, and then sync changes both ways. I know nothing about Google Docs scripts though.

Comment: Can you have multiple notes on one day?

Comment: I don't need to support that. If it occurs I would just want the first or last. See 2nd paragraph.

Comment: You can always squeeze all notes into one cell.

Comment: That would actually be best. What change would I make for that?

Comment: If you start each new comment with a hyphen, then you can use this post, here on Web Applications, to enter a new line into a cell: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25361/29140

Comment: What do you mean by this? Can you give me an example in your formula below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following formula, to keep track of the notes:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A32,Sheet2!A:B,2,0), ""))
```

If you have more than one note per day, then you can expand the formula to cover more columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A32,Sheet2!A:B,{2,3,4,5,6},0), ""))
```

Comment: To clarify I don't have extra notes in column to the right of the date. I have extra rows. It would look lite this in CSV Date,Note \n 3/2/14,"Note 1" \n 3/2/14,"Note 2" \n