# How to change the text line height in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I could not find an option in the recent version of Google Sheets to change the text line height (the spacing between lines in a single cell).

You realize the problem even more when exporting the spreadsheet as PDF, the lines are very close to each other which makes it uncomfortable to read.

Summed up, it would be helpful to adjust line heights. I like to give the text lines some spacing to each other (one long line, no splitting of the text over different cells).

Answer (score 3):

Google Sheets doesn't include a setting to customize the text line height.

One workaround is to set vertical align to Middle and change the row height to a size big enough.

[image: Toolbar button vertical align - Middle]

NOTES:

1. When the OP says "lines" they actually are meaning rows.
2. For multi-line cells, in order to increase the interline spacing, the workarounds are:

   1. Include a the size of one character on each line
   2. Insert a blank line between lines.

Related

- [How does one add a new line in a cell in a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/25359/88163)

Comment: This works only for texts with 1 line.

Comment: @srrvnn I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`CHAR(10)`** to add brute spacing like:

**`="The world"&CHAR(10)&"is mine!"`**

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, just select the lines which you want to change the height and on the index of any selected line drag as if you would normally drag to change height of single row, but here if you drag any one of the row it automatically reflects the height of all selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1. Use hard returns to split your text over multiple lines.
2. Insert empty lines in between each item.
3. Select the empty line.
4. Specify a font size for the empty line.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.modernschoolbus.com/changing-cell-padding-in-google-sheets/

I don't take any credit for the above linked article.  This should answer the OP's question regarding cell padding.  Please also note that the various ways in which PDF is created will differ.  If printing to PDF does not work, try a different method of exporting and/or different printing engines that produce PDF.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/146926)

Answer (score -2):

Select the lines you want to change line height on. Drag the lines down to height you want.